# how to get fb user id if someone install app from other wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to facebook application.so,i am little confuse. First i will tell you what i do in my app.
I have create one app.Anybody install my app then i will post on his wall.

Now i tell you What i want?
If anybody click on his post and install our app then i want to store facebook id of user whose post refer by current user?

For example: Jack install our app.After install app we post app link,message etc on jack wall.After that Mark see the post on Jack wall and mark install the app.At that time i want Jack FB userid. it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to include "poster userID" in the link first poster is sharing to his wall. This way, when other user uses this link you can get referrer userID from $_GET variable.